# What does this following code do?

Tags: perl

What does this following do? Can anybody explain me?

```
$data = "What is the STATUS of your mind right now?";

$data =~/.*/; print "$1,$2\n";

$data =~/(.*?)(u+).*/; print "$1, $2\n";

$data =~/(.?)(u+).*/; print "$1, $2\n";

$data =~/(\w+\s)+/; print "$1, $2\n";
```

What is `$1 and $2`? How does this get it's value? and what are all these regular expressions?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), which will answer all your questions.

The general reference for Perl regular expressions is [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), but you should read the tutorial first as it serves as a nicer introduction.

Comment: @Nitesh: that question is answered in the [Extracting Matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) section of the document I linked to.

Comment: @Nitesh: They are called backreferences. Have you read the links yet?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn :- No i started just now.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` and `$2` are matching variables. They refer to whatever is matched in the various parentheses matching groups in the last regular expression.

`$1` has the part of the string that was matched in the *first* parenthesis group. `$2` has the part of the string that was matched in the *second* parenthesis group. You can guess what `$3` would contain.

**Lets look at your example:**

```
$data = "What is the STATUS of your mind right now?";
$data =~/.*/; print "$1,$2\n";
```

There are no parentheses here, so $1 and $2 don't contain anything.

```
$data =~/(.*?)(u+).*/; print "$1, $2\n";
```

There are two parentheses groups here. The first one is `(.*?)`, which matches nothing or anything it can (in a non-greedy manner, but that's another topic). The second one is `(u+)` which matches one or more *"u"*s.

The first (and only) "u" in `$data` is in the middle of *"you"*, so `$1` matches everying up until the first *"u"*, and `$2` matches that one *"u"*.

```
$data =~/(.?)(u+).*/; print "$1, $2\n";
```

Now the first group is `(.?)`, which matches one single character, or nothing. Then `(u+)` again matches one or more *"u"*s.

Since there's just one *"u"* in our string, the first group will be the one single character before it, which is *"o"*, and the second group will match the actual *"u"*

```
$data =~/(\w+\s)+/; print "$1, $2\n";
```

Finally, the first group matches `(\w+\s)+`, which is one or more "word" characters followed by a whitespace character. "Word" characters are any alphanumeric character or the underscore. There is no second group, but there is that  `+` (one or more) symbol.

So what does it match up to? This is a weird one, and I'm not sure if my understanding is 100% accurate. Since the entire matching group has the `+`, it will gobble up as much of the string as it can and still match the `\w+\s`. In this case it's able to ignore everything up until the *"right "*, which it then matches as `$1`.

Then, because it has the `+`, it will look for any more matches immediately afterward, but since the *"right "* is the rightmost string matched, it won't ever find another group match.

So `$1` is "right ", and `$2` is empty.

**Summary:**

When you see $1 and $2, you should look for the matching group parentheses in the last regular expression.